# Safemint code in react web3

Tags: web3js, erc-721, react

I have the ERC721 safemint code which looks like this in etherscan:

[image]

But when I am trying to implement it in reactjs web3, I am getting an error while transaction in metamask.

The code is:

```
await SmartContract.methods.mint(to, BigNumber.from(amount)).send({
                from: defaultAccount,
                
            })
```

The 'to' and amount I am getting from form input. I am using `Bignumber` from `ethers`.
The `SmartContract` is a js file in the project with `contract address` and `ABI code`.

The error is like this in Metamask:

```
This transaction is expected to fail. Trying to execute it is expected to be expensive but fail, and is not recommended.
```

The `mint` function works fine in `Etherscan` and `solidity`.

AM I missing something here?

P.S.: In log I am getting this:

```
BigNumber.toString does not accept any parameters; base-10 is assumed
```

But I dont know if it has anything to do with the error, as I also tried without Bignumber

Comment: Try `parseUnits` instead of `BigNumber`

Comment: Where to get parseUnits? It does not seem like an export of ethers

Comment: I used utils.parseUnits. But still getting error.

Comment: `BigNumber.toString` this part of the code is missing please share it

Comment: I didnt use Bignumber anywhere else. Just the given part of the code.

Comment: ok and what if you put string directly instead of BigNumber?

Comment: I still get the same error in Metamask